# HttpClient lançando exceção org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException?

Tags: java, xml, http, jdbc

Existe alguma razão para o seguinte código lançar essa exceção? Eu tenho um `webservice` que faz consulta no meu banco e transforma tudo em [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) e depois faz um envio para um outro `webservice` pega a resposta e atualiza meu banco, tudo funciona bem até o código executar exatamente 20 vezes, depois eu recebo uma essa exceção:

> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection  org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449) org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)  org.hibernate.jdbc.BorrowedConnectionProxy.invoke(BorrowedConnectionProxy.java:74)  com.sun.proxy.$Proxy221.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)    br.com.store.dao.conexao.connect.PreparedSt(connect.java:54)    br.com.store.servlets.webservice.ImportPedidoXML.validaUsuario(ImportPedidoXML.java:137)    br.com.store.servlets.webservice.ImportPedidoXML.doPost(ImportPedidoXML.java:93)    br.com.store.servlets.webservice.ImportPedidoXML.doGet(ImportPedidoXML.java:80)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
>
> **root cause**
>
> ```
> java.sql.SQLException: Couldn't get connection because we are at maximum connection count (20/20) and there are none available
> ```

Segue o código que faz conexão com o cliente:

```java
try {
  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
  builder.setScheme("http")
    .setHost(StoreWS.getHostStatus())
    .setPath(StoreWS.getPathStatus())
    .setParameter("tx_login", StoreWS.getUsuarioStatus())
    .setParameter("tx_senha", StoreWS.getSenhaStatus())
    .setParameter("cd_pedido",
                    String.valueOf(pedido.getCd_pedido()));
  URI url = builder.build();
  HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
  HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
  String output;
  while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    resposta.append(output);
  }
  br.close();
  response.getEntity().getContent().close();
  // client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  return resposta.toString();
}
```

A exceção sempre aparece aqui, não aparece quando eu atualizo meu banco depois de receber a reposta o que faria mais sentido por ser uma exceção do `JDBC`?
Uso `Spring`, `JDBCTemplate` com `DataSource`, já tentei de tudo, aumentar o pool, mas sempre dá o mesmo problema.

Comment: Provavelmente você está conectando novamente (à cada requisição) em uma parte do pool de conexões que está como limite de 20 conexões, então ao tentar pela 21ª vez vai dar pau. Você deve tratar esta exceção como "limite de conexões simultâneas excedido" ou então utilizar a mesma transação para realizar todas as consultas, ou então fechar a conexão sempre que a consulta terminar.

Comment: Você tá abrindo 20 conexões (o máximo) e não está fechando quando termina. Daí todas as conexões ficam abertas e ele não consegue abrir uma nova. A solução do @PauloRoberto parece ser a ideal.

Comment: Isso nao pode ser possivel, após todas as conexões com o banco eu faço um close

Comment: O que o erro acusa, é exatamente o que está sendo falado. Poderia mostrar onde você faz a conexão no banco para salvar os dados?

Comment: Sinceramente, pergunta e resposta são um típico caso do [Problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/como-lidar-com-o-problema-xy). Enquanto vejo o esforço do autor em responder sua própria pergunta como algo louvável, penso que o conjunto aqui apresentado é de pouca valia para a comunidade em geral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido, era um erro de Sessão causado pelo cliente e não pelo servidor.

Comment: None of them were helpful.

Comment: Se você achou por si mesmo a solução, poste-a e a marque como aceita. Escreva como se você estivesse dando uma resposta para uma pergunta que não fosse sua, tendeu?

Comment: Foi oque eu fiz.

Answer (score -1):

O problema esta descrito na exceção, o número máximo de conexões com o banco (20) foi excedido. Você pode configurar o banco e aumentar esse número ou utilizar uma espécie de pool de conexões, aonde o sistema mantenha um número X de conexões abertas e vá utilizando as mesmas conexões para consultas diferentes. Existem inúmeras possibilidades.

Comment: Acho que isso cabe mais como comentário, não?

Comment: @PauloRoberto Como eu vou comentar com 1 ponto de reputação?

Comment: Além disso, da uma lida na pergunta: 'Existe alguma razão para o seguinte código lançar essa exceção?' Sim, existe, e a razão foi apontada na minha resposta.

Comment: Mas você não deve agir assim. Se você tem um comentário, e não pode comentar, não deve simplesmente postar como resposta. Reputação é fácil de conseguir aqui no StackOverflow, e também você pode esperar a pergunta se desenvolver mediante às conversas em comentários para posteriormente postar uma resposta concreta :) não temos pressa por aqui.

Comment: É mesmo, me conte então uma maneira fácil de conseguir reputação se não respondendo as perguntas, pois até aonde eu sei é assim que se consegue. :)

Comment: Há algumas maneiras de conseguir reputação. Você pode conseguir reputação por exemplo editando respostas e perguntas e caso suas edições forem aprovadas, você ganha +2 de reputação por cada edição aprovada. E também ao realizar uma pergunta você pode ganhar +5 de reputação cada vez que derem um voto positivo pra sua pergunta.